# Modern OpenGL shader wrapper v2

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl

This is a fixed up version (following RAII principles) of my previous reviewal. I have moved the construction of the object entirely to the constructor to prevent any bad object states.

The only thing I am slightly concerned about is if an exception is thrown, the destructor will not be called thus causing shader objects to leak (as `glDeleteShader` won't be called).

Maybe wrapping the shader handle ID (`shader_id`) in some sort of POD-wrapper could fix this?

**compilation_error.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

class CompilationError : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    CompilationError(const std::string &message, std::string info_log);

    const std::string &get_info_log() const;

private:
    const std::string info_log;
};
```

**compilation_error.cpp**

```
#include <render/shader/compilation_error.h>

CompilationError::CompilationError(const std::string &message, std::string info_log) :
    runtime_error(message), info_log(std::move(info_log)) {}

const std::string &CompilationError::get_info_log() const {
    return info_log;
}
```

**shader.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <engine.h>
#include <string>

class Shader {
public:
    Shader(GLenum type, const std::string &path);

    ~Shader();

private:
    const GLuint shader_id;
};
```

**shader.cpp**

```
#include <render/shader/shader.h>
#include <render/shader/compilation_error.h>
#include <fstream>

Shader::Shader(const GLenum type, const std::string &path) :
    shader_id(glCreateShader(type)) {
    if (!shader_id) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to create shader");
    }

    std::ifstream input_stream(path, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::ate);

    if (!input_stream) {
        glDeleteShader(shader_id);

        throw std::ifstream::failure("Unable to open shader file");
    }

    const long source_length = input_stream.tellg();
    std::vector<char> source((unsigned long) source_length);

    input_stream.seekg(0);
    input_stream.read(source.data(), source_length);

    const GLchar *sources[] = {source.data()};
    const GLint lengths[] = {(GLint) source_length};

    glShaderSource(shader_id, 1, sources, lengths);
    glCompileShader(shader_id);

    GLint compile_status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_status);

    if (!compile_status) {
        GLint log_length;
        glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &log_length);

        std::vector<GLchar> log_output((unsigned long) log_length);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader_id, log_length, nullptr, log_output.data());

        std::string info_log(log_output.data());

        if (!info_log.empty() && info_log.back() == '\n') {
            info_log.pop_back();
        }

        glDeleteShader(shader_id);

        throw CompilationError("Unable to compile shader", info_log);
    }
}

Shader::~Shader() {
    glDeleteShader(shader_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot better! Good job!

Nitty-gritty stuff:

**better cleanup in the constructor**

You hava a lot of the following idiom in the constructor:

```
if(condition) {
  glDeleteShader(shader_id);
  throw something;
}
```

This is a little fragile, since should you make the class more complex, that's a lot of places to refactor. The following would be better:

```
try {
  //most of the constructor in here
  ...
  if(condition) throw something;
  ...
}
catch(...) {
  glDeleteShader(shader_id);
  throw;
}
```

**ifstream can throw its own exceptions if you tell it to**

```
ifstream input_stream;
input_stream.exceptions( std::ios::failbit );
input_stream.open(path, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::ate);
```

**Use iterators when converting a vector to a string**

```
std::string info_log(log_output.data());
vs
std::string info_log(log_output.begin(), log_output.end());
```

The second one is better because it works whether there is a null terminator or not. It also removes a `strlen()` call from the code, which is a O(N) operation.

That's actually all I've got. Good job once again.

Comment: Thank you again, you're great! It's all starting to make sense.